# Trigger "mobileinit" event

Tags: triggers, jquery-mobile, jquery

Simple question, I guess.

How to trigger `mobileinit` event at `jQuery Mobile`?

I get some **Ajax** response, which is not `nicely` designed (in jQuery Mobile form). And I guess I have to trigger this event to get it done.

Comment: Here are the docs on MobileInit: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/globalconfig.html if you posted some example code we could help a little more

Comment: I understand how to bind on this event, I need to trigger it. For example, if `mobileinit()` was a function, I would just call it with `mobileinit()`. Now I don't know how to trigger this event...

Comment: The mobileinit event is triggered immediately upon execution, you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded. you could try $.mobileinit(); in the jQM Library itself it's called like this: $( window.document ).trigger( "mobileinit" );

Comment: That is actually exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try `$.mobileinit();` in the jQM Library itself it's called like this:

```
$( window.document ).trigger( "mobileinit" );
```

Comment: What if the the html has an included child.html and we need to invoke mobileinit there?

Answer (score 2):

I don't trust mobileinit. I am building a mobile app with Phonegap and jQueryMobile, currently testing on Android 4.0.3, and the event is just not firing. At all. It is correctly set up, since I can trigger it in the Chrome console while testing on desktop.

Binding to window instead of document makes no difference.

Of course I could trigger it in some other event handler like pagebeforecreate on the first page in the DOM. But that's putting the horse behind the cart.

Comment: Lord knows what I did after that comment, but currently Phonegap and mobileinit are working fine for me on Android and iOS (simulator).